# EXCLUDE '(' AND ')' specific characters using RegEx

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

How to exclude character `(` and `)`?

Is this command enough in postgresql?

```
where column1 ~ '^.*[^A-Za-z0-9() .-].*$'
```

Comment: Well you also seem to want to exclude alphanumeric characters.  Is that your intention?

Comment: The question is really vague. Should every row be excluded which contains at least one of the two characters? Or only those having both? Should further characters be excluded? Why to use a regex instead of simple LIKE?

Comment: Or maybe you need that these characters are removed from the text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parenthesis exclusion is right.

```sql
select '(' ~ '[(]';--true
select ')' ~ '[)]';--true
select '(' ~ '[^(]';--false
select ')' ~ '[^)]';--false
select ')()()()())(' ~ '[()]';--true
select ')()()()())(' ~ '[^()]';--false
```

But the regex is likely not doing what you want: it matches any text that has a single character unmatched by that group, anywhere in the middle. [Test it.](https://dbfiddle.uk/LvyDV0Qk) At the moment you can put an `@` and surround it by with all the characters you don't want `'AZaz09() .-@AZaz09() .-'` and that will match.

Most of the time you're better off looking up existing regular expressions and tweaking them than building your own from scratch. You might want to ask a question *how* to catch or exclude certain texts, showing some examples and specifying which ones you want, which ones you don't and what you've tried so far. Or a question *why* a regular expression you have doesn't behave like you expect it to, plus some examples of that.